# Working with dates in extensionAttributes and Get-Date

Tags: date, powershell, active-directory, quest

I'm attempting to use Active Directory extensionAttributes to keep track of certain dates (like start date, termination date, etc) so that I can trigger certain actions when that date occurs.

I'm having an issue with the different variations that a date can be entered in (M/D/YY, MM/DD/YY, MM/DD/YYYY, etc).  For example, I can use `Get-Date` to output to a format of M/D/YYYY, but I run into issues when someone enters MM/DD/YY.

Is there a way to make this work so that it can accept other variations (as long as it's month/date/year)?

Here are a couple of lines from the script in question.  This runs once a day, and checks for new users starting the following day.

```
$StartingOn = (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()

$NewUserCheck = Get-QADUser -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties extensionAttribute11 | where { $_.extensionAttribute11 -eq $StartingOn }
```

Notice how it only returns as long as the date equals the `Get-Date` output.  It was the only way I was able to get this to work properly.  Even at that, if someone typed in 07/20/15, the output would return nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to compare date strings.  Use DateTime comparison which won't care about formatting details e.g.:

```
$StartingOn = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$NewUserCheck = Get-QADUser -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties extensionAttribute11 | 
    Where { [DateTime]($_.extensionAttribute11) -eq $StartingOn}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the help.  However, I received multiple "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".  Not sure what this means exactly.

Comment: n/m. I understand the problem now. Looking for a way around it.  Is there something I can add in this command to accept null as a value?

Comment: Where is the null?  $_ or $_.extensionAttributes11?

Comment: The repeated errors are coming from the amount of empty extensionAttribute11 from the rest of the user base.  As a workaround, I populated everyone else's extensionAttribute11 with an arbitrary date.  your edited script worked great afterwards!